# PDO query in loop

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I have this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM videos";
$stmp = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmp->execute();
while ($row = $stmp->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $vkey = md5($row['id'] . "video");

    $sql = "UPDATE videos SET vkey = :vkey WHERE id = :id";
    $stmp = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmp->execute(array(
        ":vkey" => $vkey,
        ":id"   => $row['id']
    ));

}
```

Why is execute only for the first id from the first select and not for all it's in the loop?

Comment: There are two `execute()` calls in your code, one is in the loop. I guess I don't understand your question?

Comment: first select get all id's from table videos and in loop i want to execute query for each id

Comment: It’s better to fetch all into array and then loop through it https://stackoverflow.com/a/15386703/3254405

Comment: You overwrite `$stmp`. You also should prepare outside of the loop.

Comment: Why not use MySQL's [MD5()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) for a pure SQL call: `UPDATE videos SET vkey = MD5(vkey);`?

Comment: the problem here is in using `while` instead of `foreach`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could completely avoid all of that code by just doing this:

```
$db->query("UPDATE videos SET vkey = MD5(CONCAT(vkey, 'video'))");
```

(Or you could do this query in your backend like PHPMyAdmin `UPDATE videos SET vkey = MD5(CONCAT(vkey, 'video'))`)

---

However, if you for some reason want to loop through your database, you could do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM videos";

//no reason to use prepare() because you aren't passing variables.
$stmp = $db->query($sql);
$stmp->execute();
$results = $stmp->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//prepare UPDATE query outside of loop, this way you don't send 2 requests to your database for every row
$stmp = $db->prepare("UPDATE videos SET vkey = :vkey WHERE id = :id");

foreach($results as $result) {
    $vkey = md5($result['id']."video");
    $stmp->execute(
        array(
            ":vkey" => $vkey, 
            ":id" => $result['id']
        )
    );
}
```

Also, it's usually a good idea to check the return values inside the loop to make sure there were no errors, you could probably do this by using something like `$stmp->rowCount()` to check if there were any rows effected.

Comment: Is not working. Is updated only for the first id from select.

Comment: Always a good idea to check return values to ensure no errors occurred as well.

Comment: @user1964450 Glad I could help!

Comment: @miken32 I'll add that to my answer, however I'm not gonna update the code because I'm not sure how OP wants to handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need a

```
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

Otherwise the statement is stuck in the first run. You might want to check with a try...catch, echoing the error-message.

Comment: This answer should be deleted, because it's plainly wrong.