# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (); works in local environment

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am working on posting a CRUD Application to where the user logs in first. The application is made with 2 MySQL tables; one for logging in and the other for the CRUD values. This example hasn’t worked on my local environment using both XAMP/PC and MAMP/MAC.

When I uploaded it to my host it does work, however the CRUD values don’t populate when it the for each loop is specified.  I concatenated the mysql_error(); to explain why this is not working on my host.

[image: mysql_error() location]

On line 34 in logincrud/main.php:

[image: line 34 is not working]

The code from the table in main.php:

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Number</th>
                  <th>Explanation</th>
                  <th>Date Accured</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <?php
               include 'database.php';
               $pdo = Database::connect();
               $sql = 'SELECT * FROM saftey ORDER BY id DESC';
               foreach (($sql) as $row) {
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['ins_n'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['explanation'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['date'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td width=250>';
                        echo '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                        echo ' ';
                        echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                        echo ' ';
                        echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
               }
               Database::disconnect();
              ?>
              </tbody>

        </table>
```

The Add, Update, and Delete works on the host as I can see the records from the safety table on myphpadmin. The login/logoff is from a completely different table.  Again, the local environment works with no issues.

I opened a help ticket with my host provider, but all I received is they do not troubleshoot Applications.

I have been looking for solutions for a few weeks and all I couldn’t find a solution. In the Chrome browser the console states the error: hp:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()" Server issue? Aware of SQL Injection problems.

I uploaded a [GITHUB project](https://github.com/Tryah85/loginCRUDtwotables.git) if it helps.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You do not execute your SQL query. Remove `mysql_error()` as it does not exist anymore in PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: I took the mysql_error() function out of the php file, a still Invalid Argument on line 34 :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem why it was not working on my live site. Looking at this [Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385965/php-pdo-with-foreach-and-fetch) 
The way the PHP Data Object  has the forward arrow executes the code. The way this foreach works caused the value return false; in other words not in an array.

I reorganized the PHP Data Object into a variable known as $records.

```
foreach (($sql) as $row) {
```

to

```
$records = $pdo->query($sql);
                   foreach ($records as $row) {
```

changed the *echo* to *print*

```
}
```

Works now. Weird how echo is different than print in this situation.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Number</th>
                      <th>Explanation</th>
                      <th>Date Accured</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <?php
                   include 'database.php';
                   $pdo = Database::connect();
                   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM safety ORDER BY id DESC';
                   $records = $pdo->query($sql);
                   foreach ($records as $row) {
                            print '<tr>';
                            print '<td>'. $row['ins_n'] . '</td>';
                            print '<td>'. $row['explanation'] . '</td>';
                            print '<td>'. $row['date'] . '</td>';
                            print '<td width=250>';
                            print '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                            print ' ';
                            print '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                            print ' ';
                            print '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                            print '</td>';
                            print '</tr>';
                   }
                   Database::disconnect();
```

Comment: Echo and print are the same thing.

Comment: That's is what I thought too, but for some reason print worked on the host, not echo...